# Dividing a Linked list at Certain Spot

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was wondering if someone can point the way on how I can add to my function the a way for the user to choose at what point in the link list it should be split up. Currently I have one that works perfectly fine that splits the list in half. Here it is>>>

```
void split(Node *pOriginal , Node *&pHeadA, Node *&pHeadB){
  if(pOriginal ==NULL){
    cout<< "No element in list ";
  }

  else{
    pHeadA = pOriginal;
    Node *pTemp = pOriginal;
    while(pTemp != NULL && pTemp->pNext != NULL && pTemp->pNext->pNext != NULL){
      pHeadA=pHeadA->pNext;
      pTemp = pTemp->pNext->pNext;
    } // ends the while loop

    pHeadB = pHeadA->pNext;
    pHeadA->pNext = NULL;

    pHeadA = pOriginal;
    pOriginal = NULL;

  } // ends the else
} // ends the split function
```

The goal im looking for is to add another parameter and then upon user input split the linked list at a certain point. Lets say the list **1->3->5->7->9->11->13** and the user decides to split the list at **5**
the output of the list would be

**1->3->5**

and the other

**7->9->11->13**

Can someone shed some light on how i can add this to my existing function.

Comment: Can you convert that while loop to a for loop but keep the exact same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop inside your `else`<sup>1</sup> is where you locate the position to split, right?

You replace that with a different bit of code that finds the node that has the desired value (or perhaps finds the last node less than or equal to the deisred value depending on the spec).<sup>2</sup>

You will, of course, need an argument to specify the target value.

Generally you wouldn't want one function to perform both kinds of splitting, and would instead prepare separate functions.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In my view it is nicer to `return` inside the body of the `if` and let the rest of the code run at function scope rather than bothering with an `else`, but that is an esthetic decision and may (or may not) be prohibited by the coding guidelines you are working under. (I am guess you are writing this for class.)

<sup>2</sup> In my view, this is more straight forward than using double striding to approximately half the list as you are already doing.

<sup>3</sup> Perhaps named `bisect` and `partitionByValue`. Or something. Naming is important.

Comment: Hello @dmckee You are correct to assume that i am writing this for class. And as per guidelines I was instructed to keep this all in one function.